# Query to get the result between two date time stamp

Tags: oracle, datetime

I want to fetch some records which should give results based on certain time.

That means from `2.30 Am to 6.00 AM`.

I tried using the **between** function, but i am not getting.

```
 MTRDCRE between (to_char(to_date('16-03-2016 02:50:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) , to_char(to_date('16-03-2016 05:50:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')))
```

Comment: try to use > =  and < = operator .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from yourtable
where MTRDCRE >= to_char(to_date('16-03-2016 02:50:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
and MTRDCRE <= to_char(to_date('16-03-2016 05:50:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

If your column MTRDCRE is date you don't need to_char().